How to run an Azure Machine Learning pipeline from Synapse?
I have a working v2 pipeline in Azure Machine Learning that I want to run from Synapse. However, I cannot select my pipelines from the dropdown menu.
I have a working linked service and a non-self-hosted integration runtime. When I click 'Open in Azure Portal', it brings me straight to the Pipelines page in my Azure ML environment.

The pipeline is also made available as a batch endpoint in Azure ML.


How do I get Synapse to start a pipeline job in Machine Learning?

are you facing any error?

The 'Name of Machine Learning pipeline' dropdown just is empty ('no results found'), see the red underlined in the first screenshot

I got similar results when I tried the above scenario.

To resolve the above issue, make sure you publish the ML pipeline. Go to ML workspace -> Pipelines -> Pipeline endpoints and verify your pipeline endpoint should be here.

If not publish the pipeline by creating new pipeline endpoint.

Now, the pipeline will show up in the dropdown of the Synapse pipeline activity as shown below.


This is the legacy v1 'classic' experience. My pipeline is v2

Is your pipeline published? My linkedservice is same as yours?

Published is v1 jargon. My pipeline is deployed (v2). It exists as a batch endpoint.
I added a screenshot in my original question.

Give me some time, I will try as per your requirement

As per the tip in this documentation, currently ADF or synapse machine learning activity only supports the assets from Azure Machine Learning V1. To run the batch endpoint which is V2 from this ADF or synapse pipelines, you can use web activity in the pipeline and follow the step by step process which was mentioned in the same documentation and also refer this SO answer.

Or you need to use the data pipelines from Fabric to directly invoke the batch endpoint using Azure Machine learning activity. Please go through this doc to know about this process.
